# How can I access value returned after Angular $resource $save()?

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using a PHP CRUD Api to service a simple AngularJS list app.

When I add a new item to the database, I want to refresh the list to show the new item.

My idea was to push the data into the list array in the $save success callback. This works well, but I need to know the 'id' of the record that was written by the PHP API.

The PHP Api does pass back the `lastInsertId()` as can be seen in this code

```
function create($table, $data) {
    $fields = $this->filter($table, $data);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (" . implode($fields, ", ") . ") VALUES (:" . implode($fields, ", :") . ");";

    $bind = array();
    foreach($fields as $field)
        $bind[":$field"] = $data[$field];

    $result = $this->run($sql, $bind);
    return $this->db->lastInsertId();
}

$db = new db();
$rowId = $db->create($table,$data);
$requestContentType = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];
$this ->setHttpHeaders($requestContentType, $statusCode);
$response = $this->encodeJson($rowId);
echo $response;
```

The problem is, I don't know how to access the `lastInsertId()` in the success callback using the code below

```
data.$save()
    .then(function (res) {
        // push the new data in to the list array here - how do I access the lastInsertId() that is returned from the Api?
    })
    .catch(function (req) {
        // error
    })
    .finally(function () {

    });
```

Is this the best way to refresh the app after inserting a new record or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this question in the future, the problem wasn't with the `$save` function, it was a problem with the php CRUD Api - it was returning the last inserted ID alright, but not in JSON encoded format.

Once I changed the php Api to return the ID JSON encoded (e.g. `{"id": "185"}`) I could access `res.id`